# How to tell the root process to use the anaconda python installation instead of /usr/bin/python?

Tags: python, linux

I have a python script with the following shebang line on top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I have Python3 installed on my Linux box and when I run this scripts as a regular users it correctly uses the Python3 that is located in my Anaconda installation:

```
/home/user/miniconda3/bin/python
```

However, when I tried to run this as root, it will use the old python in:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

How can I tell the root process to use the Anaconda python instead of the old default /usr/bin/python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env` will read your current user's env variables. As your conda's python is in the `PATH`, so it will be used.

But `root`'s env variables are different. The simplest solution would be change `#!/usr/bin/env python` to a specific python such as `#!/home/user/miniconda3/bin/python`. It will force to use this specific python version.

Comment: Can I put conda Python bin path to my "root PATH" ?

Comment: Surely you can.